# How do I register nonconsecutive pages in i386 paging directory?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, paging, page-tables

I'm trying to write a simple OS with context switching, including mapping a separate virtual address space for each process (eg. each process gets its own page directory). If say a process's **data segment** is at memory address `0x700000`, its **code segment** is at `0x715000`, and the **stack** is scattered across multiple nonconsecutive pages as it grows, how would I map those to all be one consecutive virtual address space starting at `0x0`? I'm aware of how the page directory and page tables work, however I'm not sure how to map pages in a nonconsecutive manner (for example, if I wanted to map physical addr 0x8000 to virtual 0x10000). I can't find any tutorials or examples online, so I would appreciate it if someone explained how to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure what part you're unclear on.  It sounds like you understand where the page table entry for virtual address `0x10000` should go.  That entry has a field for the physical address of the corresponding page, and you set that to `0x8000`.  (Or rather, to `0x8` because the low bits are omitted from the field.)

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging has several examples.

Comment: *stack is scattered across multiple nonconsecutive pages as it grows* - huh?  Stack growth is always contiguous from `push` and `sub rsp, 24` and whatever, unless you have a big unused alloca or VLA so you end up never touching a page.  Or unless you actually have multiple stacks for multiple tasks, but then you wouldn't say "it" singular.

Comment: i mean the stack for a user process is scattered across physical memory; it would still be contiguous in virtual memory

Comment: Nate - so each page entry is 32 bits and only holds one address. So you’re saying that each entry index maps to a physical address? So if I were to place 0x10000 in the very first page entry, physical address 0x0 would be mapped to virtual 0x10000?

Comment: @Devin: no, it's the opposite: you're right about each entry maps to a physical address, but the index number of the page table refers to the virtual page and the value at that index is the corresponding physical frame. In your example, putting ```0x10000``` in the first entry means that virtual address ```0x0``` maps to physical address ```0x10000``` (presuming you set the correct flags in the page table entry).

Comment: Right, the PTE only contains the physical address, not the virtual address.  The virtual address is used by the MMU to find that PTE in the first place: the high 10 bits used to select an entry in the page directory, which points to a page table; the next 10 bits to select an entry in that page table.  So if you want to map a particular virtual to a particular physical address, you use the virtual address to decide which page table entry to use, and the physical address to decide what that PTE should contain.